# How can I access the request body in an IIS rewrite provider?

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I've written a custom rewrite provider using the [`IRewriteProvider` interface](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module), and installed it in IIS.  It's working, but I need to access the content of the *request* as well as the URL.  A [newsgroup posting](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/urlrewritingnet/cVNupSKPlzE/ucdwQBjmOh0J) suggests that I should be able to access `HttpContext.Current`, but in my testing it shows up as **null**.

Is there any way to get access to the request content from a rewrite provider?

Comment: Inside `Rewrite()` `HttpContext.Current` is null??

Comment: @cheesemacfly: Yep!  Any ideas on why are most welcome!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe you can solve it without the `HttpContext.Current`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly: I want to rewrite the URI based on the body of the request.  Eg. if the request body is '1', add a '1' to the URI.

Comment: I have not tested and can't really right now but have you tried `{ReplaceProvider:{ALL_HTTP}}` or `{ReplaceProvider:{ALL_RAW}}`?

Comment: All_HTTP is the way to go if Rewrite() only needs the headers! Parsing it by hand is not convenient but works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely null because it never processed any context. If you'd like to modify the url based on content, you should implement a custom IHttpModule in your application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Comment: I reckon I have to accept "you can't" as the answer.  As I mentioned below, HTTP modules [don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18005227/222481) in my case.

Comment: what if you did the re-routing in client code? if you want myaddress.com/~myswitch to go to myaddress.com/myApp/userPostData then why not do it in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

An IHttpModule class for rewriting the URL...

```
public class UrlRewriteModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
            context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(context_EndRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ...special logging of exc...
        }
    }
    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fullOrigionalpath = Request.Url.ToString();
        Context.RewritePath("...whatever you want...");
    }
}
```

And the web.config...

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewriteModule"/>
    </httpModules>
```

Comment: Unfortunately an `HttpModule` [does not allow routing between multiple applications](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18005227/222481) -- otherwise it would be a good alternative.