# Why does the StaticFile handler kick in when I rewrite a URL to my WCF service?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, url-rewriting, httpmodule

I am using an `IHttpModule` to rewrite a URL for a WCF service hosted underneath it.  In IIS this looks like:

[image]

The rewrite module is in the **root** application.  It accepts a URL like:

> (1) http://host.com/root/r/users/user.1

and rewrites it to look like:

> (2) http://host.com/root/rest/users/user.1

which then "forwards" the request to the **rest** WCF service.  The problem is, the **rest** app ends up treating *user.1* with the StaticFile handler, and I'm getting a 404.  However, if I simply visit URL (2) *directly* rather than through the rewrite module, it works fine!

If the written URL does not include an extension, it works fine through the rewrite module:

> (3) http://host.com/root/rest/users/all

Why is the StaticFile handler *only* kicking in when I rewrite the URL, and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

First off, have you tried using the built-in rewrite module for IIS 7?

[IIS7 Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)

Your question has quotation marks around "forwards" so maybe you have special needs that the Microsoft-provided module doesn't handle. If so, please disregard that suggestion.

Secondly, you should consider looking through the Handler-Mappings section of IIS in both your root application and your virtual directory. Here is a long-winded link to it on technet, but also there are ways to set handler mappings in web.config as well if you would prefer that route:

[Handler mappings in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771240%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[IIS 7 and web.config mappings instructions](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers)

Comment: Yes, IIS rewrite providers [do not offer access to the request body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733444), and so will not work for me.  Re: handlers, yes, I can add a `path="*.*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"` to my **rest** app, and URL (2) will work.  I'm more wondering why that's necessary *only* in the rewrite case, and if there's a way to avoid having to add it.

Comment: Perhaps it's an undocumented or poorly documented behavior of `Server.Transfer`, or whatever method you are using to move requests between the root application and the virtual directory application? Here's an experiment, try adding the handler to your root app and see if that fixes it for the virtual rest app. If it does, then you know your `IHttpModule` is using your root app's handler mappings.